# Is a cut off frequency of 20HZ for low pass filter common (gesture recognition)?

Tags: filters

I'm doing gesture recognition based on accelerometer and gyroscope data (based on a smartwatch). I recorded the following two gestures (a) rotation and (b) double-tap.

I now have difficulties determining the optimal cut off frequency for the low pass filter in the frequency domain. As you can see in the plots, for the gyroscope there are still peaks in the frequency domain plot up until 20HZ, whereas for the accelerometer there are only peaks up until 5-6HZ for the rotation gesture. (for the double tap both have peaks until 20HZ).

I was wondering, if a cut off frequency of around 20 HZ is common for gestures?[image]